# C# Launch program with no user logged in

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a service that start an app to capture screen but when user logs off that program is terminated, do I need that my service restart my app on lock screen.

A bit of my code

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
            this.timer.AutoReset = true;
            this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
            this.timer.Start();
            this.EventLog.WriteEntry("Timer set");
            MyLog.WriteLog("Timer set");
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.EventLog.WriteEntry("Calling notepad");
            MyLog.WriteLog("Tick tock motherf*ck*");                
            try
            {
                ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser("notepad.exe")
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MyLog.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably your service is started as "Local System account" with checkbox "Allow service to interact with desktop".

Comment: yes my  service is started as "Local System account"

Comment: There is a reason that "Allow service to interact with desktop" is no longer allowed.  This is exactly what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you could use the task scheduler to accomplish this in a better way?